Minted - Automatically disabling line numbers for specific lines
My goal is to format the line numbers in the minted output so they align more closely with the desired output image.
Specifically, the numbers should align to the left when they do not have two digits. Additionally lines containing the class keyword should not display a line number. A manual solution to achieve this is also acceptable.
This is my current output


This is my desired output


Not Working MWE
% arara: lualatex
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
\documentclass[preview, margin=2mm]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}

% lualatex needed for font selection
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=-9pt,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm
}

% In order to customize the display style of line numbers (taken from the documentation of minted)
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{
    \ttfamily\footnotesize
    \arabic{FancyVerbLine}% <- important, do not remove
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
class KHOP (...): # K-hop neighborhood sampling
    def __init__(graph, n_hops=3, sizes=[...], ...):
      ...
    def sample(self, minibatch, ...):
      nbrs = samples.push(minibatch)
      for i in range(n_hops)
        # select neighbors for each vertex
        nbrs = uniform_select(nbrs, sizes[i])
        samples.push(nbrs)
      return samples
class GCN (...):  # graph convolutional network
    def __init__(self, n_layers=3, ...):
      for i in range(n_layers):
        layers[i] = GraphConv(...)  # set NN layers
      ...
    def forward(self, samples, in_feats, ...):
      out_feats = in_feats
      for i in range(n_layers):
        out_feats = layers[i](samples.pop(), out_feats)
      return out_feats
\end{minted}

\end{document}


Related Algorithm2e - Disabling line numbers for specific lines

Related Unnumbered lines in algorithm

You can simply redefine the \theFancyVerbLine macro to not print anything for line 1 and 11 (make this redefinition locally to avoid affecting other minted environments as well).
% arara: lualatex
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
% \documentclass[preview, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}

% lualatex needed for font selection
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=-9pt,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm
}

% In order to customize the display style of line numbers (taken from the documentation of minted)
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{%
    \ttfamily\footnotesize
    \arabic{FancyVerbLine}% <- important, do not remove
    \hfill % left alignment
}

\begin{document}


\begingroup
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{%
    \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=1
    \else\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=11
    \else
      \ttfamily\footnotesize
      \arabic{FancyVerbLine}% <- important, do not remove
      \hfill % left alignment
    \fi\fi
}
\begin{minted}{python}
class KHOP (...): # K-hop neighborhood sampling
    def __init__(graph, n_hops=3, sizes=[...], ...):
      ...
    def sample(self, minibatch, ...):
      nbrs = samples.push(minibatch)
      for i in range(n_hops)
        # select neighbors for each vertex
        nbrs = uniform_select(nbrs, sizes[i])
        samples.push(nbrs)
      return samples
class GCN (...):  # graph convolutional network
    def __init__(self, n_layers=3, ...):
      for i in range(n_layers):
        layers[i] = GraphConv(...)  # set NN layers
      ...
    def forward(self, samples, in_feats, ...):
      out_feats = in_feats
      for i in range(n_layers):
        out_feats = layers[i](samples.pop(), out_feats)
      return out_feats
\end{minted}
\endgroup

\end{document}



EDIT:
A version that also skips counting these lines, and allows a comma separated list of line numbers to be skipped. Please note that this list must contain string representations of the numbers (so a verbatim 12 to skip the first line 12, there is no macro expansion or integer based expansion here).
Since the sequence variable is manipulated globally and skipped lines are removed from it you can omit the groups around the minted block if you want (but it'll slow down processing a tiny bit if your other minted blocks don't need this filtering).
% arara: lualatex
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
% \documentclass[preview, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}

% lualatex needed for font selection
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=-9pt,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm
}

% In order to customize the display style of line numbers (taken from the documentation of minted)
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{%
    \ttfamily\footnotesize
    \arabic{FancyVerbLine}% <- important, do not remove
    \hfill % left alignment
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_emanuelenardi_patched_bool
\seq_new:N \g_emanuelenardi_skip_lines_seq
\cs_new:Nn \__emanuelenardi_theFancyVerbLine: {}
\NewDocumentCommand\SkipFancyVrbLines{m}
  {%
    \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_emanuelenardi_skip_lines_seq {#1}
    \bool_if:NF \l_emanuelenardi_patched_bool
      {
        \DeclareCommandCopy \__emanuelenardi_theFancyVerbLine: \theFancyVerbLine
        \cs_set_protected:Npn \theFancyVerbLine
          {
            \seq_if_in:NeTF
              \g_emanuelenardi_skip_lines_seq
              { \the\value { FancyVerbLine } }
              {
                \seq_gremove_all:Ne
                  \g_emanuelenardi_skip_lines_seq
                  { \the\value { FancyVerbLine } }
                \addtocounter { FancyVerbLine } { -1 }
              }
              { \__emanuelenardi_theFancyVerbLine: }
          }
        \bool_set_true:N \l_emanuelenardi_patched_bool
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\begingroup
\SkipFancyVrbLines{1,10}
\begin{minted}{python}
class KHOP (...): # K-hop neighborhood sampling
    def __init__(graph, n_hops=3, sizes=[...], ...):
      ...
    def sample(self, minibatch, ...):
      nbrs = samples.push(minibatch)
      for i in range(n_hops)
        # select neighbors for each vertex
        nbrs = uniform_select(nbrs, sizes[i])
        samples.push(nbrs)
      return samples
class GCN (...):  # graph convolutional network
    def __init__(self, n_layers=3, ...):
      for i in range(n_layers):
        layers[i] = GraphConv(...)  # set NN layers
      ...
    def forward(self, samples, in_feats, ...):
      out_feats = in_feats
      for i in range(n_layers):
        out_feats = layers[i](samples.pop(), out_feats)
      return out_feats
\end{minted}
\endgroup

\end{document}


If FancyVerbLine is a counter, could you include something like \addtocounter{FancyVerbLine}{-1} to make it behave as shown in the example?

To make the solution more scalable, would it be possible to specify a list of numbers, such as {1, 11-14, 15, 17-21}, and ensure that those lines are excluded from the numbering?

I was considering a more convenient approach: creating a new command in the preamble to use just before the minted environment. It could look something like:
\NewDocumentCommand{\ExcludeNumberingMinted}{<list>} {<saveDefOfFancyVerbLine> <processList and, for each line in the list, redefine it to skip printing and decrement the counter> <restoreDefOfFancyVerbLine>}

It would be great to suggest to Geoffrey Poore to incorporate this functionality directly into the package as a local option for each minted environment.

@EmanueleNardi done.
